# gnu parallel multithreading pipe uses little CPU% but stalls server

Tags: gnu-parallel

I use gnu `parallel` to run a pipe on multiple files in parallel. My code does what it should, however, if specifying the max. number of CPU (in my case 64) each job uses <5% from each CPU (based on `htop` ). In addition, the number of tasks and thr. (again based on `htop`) go through the roof which eventually kills the server. If I specify only 30 cores in gnu `parallel` it runs fine. Does anyone know how to max. out the power of the server?

My command is a pipe of different tools to trim genomic reads:

```
parallel --jobs 64 "echo -e '\n'{} processing 1>&2 ; \
gunzip -c {} | scriptA.sh | scriptB.sh -outfmt fasta \
| java -jar scriptC.jar |bgzip \
> ${output}/tmp/{/.}.filtered.tmp.fa.gz " ::: ${input} 2> ${output}/0log_parallel_stderr.log
```

Comment: Your problem is probably about Disk I/O and not about the processor usage, that is because you see <5% of processor, and by running a lot of threads you are able to stalls the server, and another thing for you consideration is the memory usage for each thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luciano says in the comment, disk I/O is most likely the cause.

The reason for getting more processes is that your pipeline will start at least 5 processes. So you should see at least 64*5 processes being started. Some of these may also start several threads.

Parallel disk I/O is very unpredictable (See https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/), and it is in practice impossible to say how many jobs in parallel is the optimal, because it depends on so many factors.

So to optimize your flow, I would adjust the number of jobs until you got the most throughput. You can use --joblog to help you see how long each job runs.

Comment: Thx for pointing out the --joblog flag Ole Tange. I will check it out and get back here if any further trouble shows up.